# Entity Framework Linking tables

Tags: entity-framework-5, hyperlink

I’m using Entity Framework 5.0,

Scenario

**"Organisation"** has a list of **"clients"** and a list of **"Periods"** and a **"CurrentPeriodID"** At the start of each period some or all of the **"Clients"** are associated with that **"Period"**, this I have done using a link table and this works OK so when I do **"Organisation->Period->Clients"** I get a list of **"Clients"** for the **"Period"**.

Next I need to add some objects (**"Activities"**) to the **"Clients"** for a **"Period"** so I get **"Organisation->Period->Client->Activates"** this won’t be the only one there will eventually be several other navigation properties that will need to be added to the **"Clients"** and the **"Activities"** and all of them have to be **"Period"** related, I also will have to be able to do (if possible) **"Organisation->Period-Activities"**.

Question

What would be the best way of implementing the **"Activities"** for the **"Organisation->Period-Client"**, I Don’t mind what way it is done Code First reverse Engineering etc. Also on the creation of the **"Organisation"** object could I load a current **"Period"** object using the **"CurrentPeriodID"** value  which is stored in the **"Organisation"** object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you need an additional entity that connects `Period`, `Client` and `Activity`, let's call it `ClientActivityInPeriod`. This entity - and the corresponding table - would have three foreign keys and three references (and no collections). I would make the primary key of that entity a composition of the three foreign keys because that combination must be unique, I guess. It would look like this (in Code-First style):

```cs
public class ClientActivityInPeriod
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Period"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Client"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Activity"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public Period Period { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

All three foreign keys are *required* (because the properties are not nullable).

`Period`, `Client` and `Activity` can have collections refering to this entity (but they don't need to), for example in `Period`:

```cs
public class Period
{
    [Key]
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClientActivityInPeriod> ClientActivities { get; set; }
}
```

You can't have navigation properties like a collection of `Clients` in `Period` that would contain all clients that have any activities in the given period because it would require to have a foreign key from `Client` to `Period` or a many-to-many link table between `Client` and `Period`. Foreign key or link table would only be populated if the client has activities in that `Period`. Neither EF nor database is going to help you with such a business logic. You had to program this and ensure that the relationship is updated correctly if activities are added or removed from the period - which is error prone and a risk for your data consistency.

Instead you would fetch the clients that have activities in a given period `1` by a query, not by a navigation property, for example with:

```cs
var clientsWithActivitiesInPeriod1 = context.Periods
    .Where(p => p.PeriodId == 1)
    .SelectMany(p => p.ClientActivities.Select(ca => ca.Client))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```